# BASH/SED with '$' substitution doesn't work

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bash script that lists subprograms/processes that could if the user chooses to, insert startupflags to a specific program. I want to match strings in the below formats and depending on which pgm the user chooses I want to insert/replace the string with the new flag infront of {PGMPATH}/pgm. The existing programs are listed in a startupfile according to something like this:

```
start -existingFlag ${PGMPATH}/pgm
start -existingFlag -anotherExistingFlag ${PGMPATH}/anotherPgm
start -existingFlag -anotherFlag ${PGMPATH}/yetAnotherPgm otherStuff
```

But to start with I try to match toward a hardcoded string (in the future toward the lines in the startup file):

```
start -existingFlag ${PGMPATH}\/pgm*
```

and replace it with a new line looking like this:

```
*start -existingFlag -newFlag ${PGMPATH}\/pgm*
```

From script:

```
existingString="start -existingFlag ${PGMPATH}\/pgm"
newString="start -existingFlag -newFlag ${PGMPATH}\/pgm"
sed 's/$replaceString/$newString/g' $STARTUPCONFFILE
```

This works (the string is replaced) as long as there is no '$' (just before {PGMPATH}) in the strings, but as soon as I add '$' as in ${PGMPATH} SED doesn't replace. I have tried a lot but I can't get it to work.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double quotes for the shell to expand variables:

```
$ set newString=1                                                         
$ set replaceString=one

# using single quotes: no expansion -> no replacement!              
$ echo one | sed 's/$replaceString/$newString/g'
one

# using double quotes: expansion -> replacement!
$ echo one | sed "s/$replaceString/$newString/g"
1
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `echo $PATH` print? Are you aware that PATH is usually a colon separated list of directories? Is this really what you want? It would expand to, e.g.

```
start -existingFlag /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin/pgm
```

which is most certainly not what you expect. Maybe you have a variable name clash and should use another name than `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Stupid me. I tried to simplify things and accidently choose the name PATH (wasn't in the real script) without thinking of the PATH environment variable. I have updated with another name

Comment: Ah, okay. Then your problem is that there is no *parameter substitution* in single quotes. `'$HOME'` is `$HOME`, while `"$HOME"` will expand to `/home/username`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there will be slashes in $PGMPATH. They will interfere with sed syntax.

You can use other character, like | or % as separator, instead of usual `/`.
e.g. try:

```
sed "s|$replaceString|$newString|g"
```

Alternately, you can use `\%regexp%` syntax, given in [sed manual here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses). (I have not used it myself though..)

Another alternate option, is to escape all the slashes in $PGMPATH, using another line of sed; but that would be more difficult.

Also, as pointed to by sudo_O, I have changed the single quote to double quotes, since the variables won't expand, when quoted with single quotes.